# Error : could not find function "collocations"

Tags: r

I need to create word cloud which include composed words. In this link [Making a wordcloud, but with combined words?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36479780/making-a-wordcloud-but-with-combined-words)
 I find the response where I should use `quanteda` library. I installed  it but when I start to adapt the code posed in the above link here:

```
# detect the collocations
colls <- collocations(docs, n = 200, size = 2)
```

The program returns this error:

> Error in collocations(docs, n = 1500, size = 2) :    could not find
>   function "collocations"

It's really weird because according to https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/quanteda/versions/0.9.6-9/topics/collocations

the `docs` should be a `Corpus` object which is the case :

```
> class(docs)
[1] "SimpleCorpus" "Corpus"
```

what do you think?
thank you for your suggestions !

Answer (score 0):

Have u library() your package?
If u do not, try

```
library("quanteda")
```

Comment: as I said , it is not a problem of package !

Comment: In the documentation they have written *the textstat_() functions formerly in quanteda have now been moved to the quanteda.textstats
package.* Hence we have to install the  ** quanteda.texstats library** to call the function.

Answer (score 0):

`textstat_collocations` is the only function of that package similar to that you are looking for:

```
colls <- textstat_collocations(docs, n = 200, size = 2)
```

I think they just changed it's name. As you can see in the documentation:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/quanteda/quanteda.pdf

There is only a `textstat_collocations` function.

Answer (score 0):

When I added the fully qualified name from the documentation

`myVar <- quanteda.textstats::textstat_collocations(.....)`

RStudio installed the quanteda.textstats library and now is working.